# Convert char to binary

Tags: c, binary, shift

I've been working on a project in which we are required to convert the letters of a name into their binary equivalents.

Part A requires us to:

> Display (write) each bit by alphabet '0' or '1' in each byte of
>   your last name, e.g.

Part B requires us to:

> Use the first character from the entered name as a mask-in
>   (bitwise OR) mask for other characters and display them out
>   like that in part A.

My code for part A works and outputs the correct binary sequence.

Output: http://imgur.com/kAAhHyc

Unfortunately my code does not seem to be working for part B.

My code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoHiM.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    int i;
    int len;
    char name[20];
    char len_str[20];
    char a;
    int x = 0;
    int num;
    int num2;
    int y;
    char  a1;
    char a2;
    int z;
    int num3;

    write(1, "Enter your name: ", 17);
    len = read(0, name, 20);
    len--;  

    num = len;
    num2 = len;
    num3 = len;
/* part 1--------------------------------------*/
    while (num > 0) {
    a = name[x];
    printf(&a);
    printf(" ");

    int mask = 128; 
    while (mask > 0) {
        printf("%d", (a & mask) > 0);
        printf(" ");
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    x = x + 1;
    printf("\n");
    num--;

    }

    printf("\n");

/* part 2--------------------------------------*/
    y = 0;
    while (num2 > 0) {
    a1 = name[y];
    int mask2 = name[0];
    printf("0");
    printf(" ");
    while (mask2 > 0) {
        printf("%d", (a1 | mask2) > 0);
        printf(" ");
        mask2 >>= 1;
        a1 <<= 1;
    }
    y = y + 1;
    printf("\n");
    num2--;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

As you can see from my code and from the output (Part A output is the first binary block, part B is the second) I posted above something appears to be wrong.  I am shifting the bits in the mask and in the letters at the same time but I am getting the incorrect output.  I changed the AND "&" to an OR "|".  The mask is the first letter of the name, ie name[0], instead of 128 as I have it in part A.  Even when I shift the bits in both in the same direction, ie mask2 >>= 1 and a1 >>= I still get the wrong output.  Could someone assist me in figuring this out.  I know I am close, it has to be some small mistake that is holding me up.

Thank you

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079583/convert-char-array-to-binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code to display the binary output in a function, call it `void showBinary(char ch)`.

The the first part is saying to do `showBinary(name[x])`, for x in `[0, strlen(name))`.

The the second part is saying to do `showBinary(name[0] | name[x])`, for x in `[1, strlen(name))`.

In both tasks, *only* the input and invocations of the "showBinary" operation changes. The actual code/operation of "showBinary" is the *same*.

Using a function to name this operation and group the code makes the distinction more clear and enables the difference to be more readily identified from a logical viewpoint. In this case that difference is the [incorrect] change to `(a1 | mask2)` *inside* the "showBinary" function's loop in the second case.

Comment: So for part 2 something like this: y = 1, instead of y = 0?

Comment: That is one change, yes (so that the character used as the OR-mask is not itself displayed, which might be my incorrect reading of the task but it is irrelevant to other logical issues). However, and *more importantly*, change `printf("%d", (a1 | mask2) > 0);` back so it looks like the *first* "showBinary", and remove `a1 <<= 1`. Then correctly apply the bitwise-OR operation to a1 *before* it is used in the "showBinary" operation/loop. I recommend using a function and following the high-level outline above to make this more apparent.

Comment: I was able to correct the code by setting a1 = name[0] | name[y] and removing the a1 bit shift.  It now outputs what I want.  Thank you for your help.